# Google Analytics Fetch Custom Report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to display data from Google Analytics on a custom dashboard built in React.JS. I've created a custom report in my Google Analytics dashboard and want to make a GET call to retrieve this custom report to get the report's data.

The [GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) only shows an example for constructing your own custom report with the query, not actually making a call for an already created custom report. Is there a way of making a GET call to a specific custom report to get its data?

This is an example provided by Google Analytics

```
function queryReports() {
gapi.client.request({
  path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
  root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    reportRequests: [
      {
        viewId: VIEW_ID,
        dateRanges: [
          {
            startDate: '7daysAgo',
            endDate: 'today'
          }
        ],
        metrics: [
          {
            expression: 'ga:sessions'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no other way to access user's custom reports programmatically, you'd probably need to save the reporting request on your side to reuse it. Each request to reporting API `batchGet` endpoint should contain an explicitly provided reportRequests object.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation